Как закрыть tkinter.messagebox через определенное время?
Как закрыть tkinter.messagebox через определенное время? Что  бы сообщение отображалось, например, 20 сек, а потом исчезало.

Никак. Сделайте свое окно через класс Toplevel, в нем добавьте автозакрытие.
